# How to return to the initial passage after we have clicked on a footnote

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

I wish to copy the model of wikipedia regarding the footnotes: when we click on one in the main text, we go the text of the footnote and return to the main text thanks to a link like ^ positioned on the left.
Can have the same behavior in latex ?
I use hyperref already.

Comment: Do [Footnote backreference with hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32401/35864) and the [`footnotebackref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnotebackref) help?