# Latex in text link to bibtex or footnote, and bibtex/footnote link back to place in text

Tags: bibtex, back-referencing

In Latex, what I would like to is have a link from a paragraph to a footnote or BibTeX reference, and have a link in the footnote or BibTeX reference back to the paragraph or place in the text where the original link was clicked. Create a circular link reference if you will. References will only be used once.

This may be a bad/non-latex example of what I want, but it demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2014-09-24/sec-is-worried-that-pimco-bought-some-little-bonds-matt-levine

In this article, I can click the superscript in the article to go to the footnote, AND you can click the superscript next to the footnote to go to where it's used in the article! Which is what I want to do for my references in Latex.

Comment: Have you thought how would you manage the 'back-references' in the bibliography if you have cited it more than just once? Should it link to the first point where it was cited? Or should it be 'empty' until yo click in a citation and then save that point? I think the latter is a very interesting feature, but I'm not sure if it can be done with rather static format. On the former, I'd be glad to see an answer :D.

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral i'll update the questions, references will only be cited once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a look around just found about the `pagebackref` option in the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package, which can be loaded this way:

```
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
```

It uses [`backref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/backref), so you can modify the formatting as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183702/formatting-back-references-in-bibliography-bibtex).

This provides the back references for the references shown in the bibliography, not for footnotes. A [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32401/footnote-backreference-with-hyperref) some years ago led to a package named [`footnotebackref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32401/footnote-backreference-with-hyperref) which relies on `hyperref` to provide the feature you requested.

However, `backref` is not compatible with [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), thus the previous solution will work if you use [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) to manage references. You can have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36307/formatting-back-references-in-bibliography) to have the bibliography back reference done with `biblatex`.

I haven't checked if `footnotebackref` is compatible with `biblatex`. Since `biblatex` can also print bibliography references as footnotes with back references, I suppose they may crash, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It even works with multiple backreferences and is so easy to implement! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.