# Linking footnotes back to the original text using the biblatex-chicago package

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing, chicago-style

I am currently working on an e-book using Latex and Biber. The package that I am using for footnotes is the `biblatex-chicago` package.

I can successfully link to a footnote from, say, a paragraph, but I would like to be able to click the actual footnote and return to the original place, creating a back-reference. I have viewed some of the other posts related to similar topics, but none that seem to work with the `biblatex-chicago` package, with which I use `\autocite` to create my foot notes.

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{book} 
\usepackage{palatino} 
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago} 
    \addbibresource{mweBib.bib} 
\usepackage{footnotebackref} 
\usepackage{tocloft} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
    \date{} \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{color} 
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, linktoc=all}
\begin{document} 
    This is a test for footnotebackref.\autocite[100]{test}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I hope that I have stated my problem clearly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The package [`footnotebackref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnotebackref) from [Footnote backreference with hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32401/35864) works like a charm here, even with `biblatex-chicago`'s footnote citations. Can you prepare a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of how it didn't work for you?

Comment: @moewe Thank you for your reply! Here is my MWE: `\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\date{}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, linktoc=all}
\addbibresource{mweBib.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a test for footnotebackref.\autocite[100]{test}

\printbibliography]
\end{document}` Am I missing something with footnotebackref?

Comment: Ahh, I will admit that the option `numberlinked=true` is somehow impaired by `biblatex` patching the `\footnote` commands, if you use `\usepackage[symbol=$\wedge$]{footnotebackref}` it works, though. Maybe I can get around to finding a work-around for the numberlink option later...

Comment: So it wasn't `biblatex` patching `\footnote` commands, it was `biblatex-chicago`'s redefining the look of the footnotes.... I really didn't expect that.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed thanks to `biblatex-chicago` that the [`footnotebackref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnotebackref) does not work.
In `biblatex-chicago.sty`, we find

```
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% Provides in-line footnote marks
      \setlength\parindent{1em}%
      \noindent
      \makebox[2.3em][r]{\@thefnmark.\,\,}#1}
```

This is executed whenever we load a non-`memoir` document class.
Unfortunately, `footnotebackref` cannot modify this macro and so we will have to do it ourselves.

The code below does not even need to load `footnotebackref`, the most important aspects can be implemented with a few lines of code (which were taken from [`footnotebackref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnotebackref)/[Holle's answer to *Footnote backreference with hyperref*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32401/35864) verbosely)

```
\newcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\footnote}    
    {\refstepcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
     \edef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
     \label{\BackrefFootnoteTag}}
    {}{}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% Provides in-line footnote marks
  \setlength\parindent{1em}%
  \noindent
  \makebox[2.3em][r]{\hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\@thefnmark}.\,\,}#1}
\makeatother
```

In the last lines we modify `biblatex-chicago`'s macro to include the link to the footnote.

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\footnote}    
    {\refstepcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
     \edef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
     \label{\BackrefFootnoteTag}}
    {}{}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% Provides in-line footnote marks
  \setlength\parindent{1em}%
  \noindent
  \makebox[2.3em][r]{\hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\@thefnmark}.\,\,}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a test for footnotebackref.\autocite[100]{wilde}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: footnote number now with backref]